# Solving an ODE with ode45 after interpolating

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration

I am working with the following code and can't find what is wrong:

```
xx = 0:1/50:1;
v = 3.*exp(-xx)-0.4*xx;
xq = xx;
vq = @(xq) interp1(xx,v,xq);

tspan = 0:1/50:1;
x0 = 3;
[~, y2] = ode45(@(t,x)vq(x), tspan, x0);
```

I get that `y2 = [3;NAN;NAN;NAN,.....]`. Yet, when I plot both equations before calling `ode45`, I get that they are equal, which is not a surprise.

When I compute:

```
f = @(t,r) 3.*exp(-r)-0.4*r;
[~, y] = ode45(f,tspan,x0);
```

it works fine. But I need to show that I can get the same results if I interpolate. Why is that not working?

Comment: `y3`? There's no `y3` in the code you've shown. Also your equation for `f`, that you say works, makes no sense – it's not a function of `t` or `r`.

Comment: I have now fixed the code, sorry, I should be more careful before I post a question! sorry @horchler. 'f' is a function of 'r' and 't' even though I only have 'r' in 'f'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `NaN` because that is the default returned by [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) for values outside of the interval spanned by `xx`. In you case, `xx` only varies from `0` to `1`. But your initial condition is at `3`. If you're going to use interpolation you need start inside of the interval defined by your data and make sure you stay there. For example, if you simply change your initial condition:

```
xx = 0:1/50:1;
v = 3.*exp(-xx)-0.4*xx;
xq = xx;
vq = @(xq) interp1(xx,v,xq);

tspan = 0:1/50:1;
x0 = 0.1;
[t, y2] = ode45(@(t,x)vq(x), tspan, x0);

f = @(t,r) 3.*exp(-r)-0.4*r;
[t, y] = ode45(f,tspan,x0);

figure;
subplot(211)
plot(t,y,'b',t,y2,'r--')
subplot(212)
plot(t,abs(y-y2))
xlabel('t')
ylabel('Absolute Error')
```

Even with this initial condition, because of the exponential growth, at a certain point the state of the system leaves your [0, 1] interval and `y2` will become `NaN`. You can tell `interp1` to use [actual extrapolation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#input_argument_extrapolation) if you prefer though.

Comment: Thanks @horchler, I have gone trough the math and you are right! I am outside the [0 1] interval.